# mySQL UPDATE or INSERT or DELETE in one statement

Tags: mysql, spl

I have a quite large Excel file (about 40.000 rows) which needs to be inserted in a mySQL DB on a frequent basis.  Thanks to [Spout](https://opensource.box.com/spout/) I can read the file without hassle, but I got stuck with the SQL-Statement. The Excel looks like this

| id | first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23334 | Mark | Spencer |
| 342217 | Gerald | Butler |

and I need to insert IDs that are currently not in my table, update if they are in the table already, and delete them from the table if they are not in the Excel anymore. Due to the massive number of rows I'd like to use as few SQL-Statements as possible so that I do not run in any problems with memory size or script timeout.

Update / Insert where quite easy with

```
INSERT INTO myTable (ID, FirstName, LastName) VALUES (:id, :firstname, :lastname) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
      FirstName = VALUES(FirstName), 
      LastName = VALUES(LastName)
```

But I cannot find a way to add the delete statement without adding another query. Does anybody know a solution?

Comment: Navicat has the ability to import Excel into a database，Can be added or updated

Comment: "insert if not exists, update is exists and delete if not in excel"... that sounds like a job for `TRUNCATE table; INSERT <all records>`.

Comment: there is no way to do it with one sql query. a temporary table is used for optimization of similar tasks. With one sql statement you pour all the data into the temporary table. then delete all records that do not exist in it, update the existing ones and insert the new ones. The last 3 requests are fast because no data is submitted with them but already existing records are processed.

Comment: The number of sql statements do not influence the number and type of operations you need to do, so combining alll 3 statement types into one would not have much impact on the speed compared to having a separate delete statement.

Comment: 40,000 rows is not massive in sql terms. What's not clear is if the file contains on average 40,000 rows and what they consist of eg lots of new records and a few updates and therefore the target table will potentially grow after each load meaning truncate is not an option.

Comment: TRUNCATE is not an option, as the table holds other persons that come from another source and are never part of the import. Those persons are flagged so I can exclude them from any DELETE statement.

Comment: @Torf, then you use `DELETE FROM table WHERE flagged=false; INSERT <<all records>>`

Comment: So in a word no. There are `INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, REPLACE`. That's it.